# Minimal example of pandoc conversion from markdown to pdf with bbitex citations

Tags: pandoc, bibtex

I must be missing something terribly obvious but after a lot of banging my head against the docs and examples, I still can't get pandoc to process bibtex/biblatex citations properly. I'm using pandoc v3.1.8.

My `document.md` file:

```
---
bibliography: bibliography.bib
---

# Foo bar baz

Lorem ipsum [@foo].

# References
```

My `bibliography.bib` file:

```
@article{foo,
    author = {Smith, J.},
    journal = {Journal of Interesting Findings},
    number = {1},
    title = {An interesting finding},
    volume = {1},
    year = {2023},
    }
```

My command line:

```bash
pandoc document.md -o document.pdf -f commonmark_x --citeproc
```

What am I doing wrong? This output is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, commonmark_x doesn't support citations yet. You'll have to use pandoc Markdown.

The corresponding issue is https://github.com/jgm/commonmark-hs/issues/15.